# How to call a function from the quotation of a invoke in type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers, quotations

I have a type provider which gives me the error "Type mismatch when splicing expression into quotation literal".

I extracted the code below in order to reproduce the issue in a smaller context.

```
let f (s : string) : string = s //some dummy implementation

let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "Root", Some typeof<obj>)
let ctor = ProvidedConstructor(parameters = [],
                               InvokeCode = (fun args -> <@@ "root" :> obj @@>)) :> MemberInfo

let prop = ProvidedProperty(propertyName = "SomeProperty",
                            parameters = [],
                            propertyType = typeof<string>,
                            GetterCode = (fun args -> <@@ f %%(args.[0]) @@>)) :> MemberInfo

do  t.AddMembers [ctor; prop]
    t.SetBaseType typeof<obj>
```

...and when I use the type provider like

```
let root = Provided.Root()

let a = root.SomeProperty
```

I get the error:

> Error: The type provider 'typeproviders.providerpoc+MyProvider' reported an error in the context of provided type 
>   'typeproviders.providerpoc.Provided.Root', member 'get_Menu'.
>
> The error: Type mismatch when splicing expression into quotation
>   literal.
>
> The type of the expression tree being inserted doesn't match
>   the type expected by the splicing operation.
>
> Expected 'System.Object', but received type 'System.String'.
>
> Consider type-annotating with the expected expression type, e.g., (%% x :
>   string) or (%x : string).. Parameter name: receivedType.

How can I write the quotation to be able to call a function inside the quotation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried type-annotating with expected type as the error message tells you?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - the message is a bit misleading because the `string` part of it is just an example not related to the actual type mismatch, and represents the _expected_ type, not the _received_ type.  So you actually would need to use `%%(args.[0] : obj)`, but that won't fix anything by itself since `f` expects a string.  Tomas's answer shows the right way to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the error message is saying is that you are putting a quoted expression of type `obj` in a place where a quoted expression of type `string` is expected.

I suspect this is happening when creating the `GetterCode` in the provided property:

```
GetterCode = (fun args -> <@@ f %%(args.[0]) @@>)
```

Here, `args` is an array of quoted expressions where each expression is of type `obj`, but the function `f` expects a string and so the quotation filling the hole using `%%` should be of type `string`

Adding a type conversion that would turn the `obj` into `string` should do the trick:

```
GetterCode = (fun args -> <@@ f (unbox<string> (%%(args.[0]))) @@>)
```